# Why doesn't Relic Shield execute always work on Thresh?

Tags: league-of-legends

When I go to use my Relic Shield stacks to execute a minion, it doesn't always work. Why is that?

I know that Relic Shield says "melee auto-attacks execute minions", but since Thresh can't buy Hurricane, doesn't that mean his auto-attacks are melee?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relic Shield does not execute on Thresh because **Thresh is a ranged champion** in every single possible mechanic in the game. The game engine NEVER considers Thresh a melee champion. His attacks are in the same group as Kayle's Righteous Fury and Vel'Koz attacks, as they are ranged attacks that are not projectiles.

Your assumption that Thresh cannot buy Runaan's Hurricane is wrong: he can buy it and it works, firing two extra bolts every time Thresh attacks. There have been patches where Thresh couldn't purchase Runaan's Hurricane, but it has been corrected since [patch 5.23](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-523-notes/) (section Bugfixes).

As every other ranged champion, Thresh can use Targon's line (Relic Shield and its upgrades) but do not receive the bonus execution on lane minions. It's a very common item on Thresh because of the desired extra health and the fact that his Flay passive will usually store enough damage to easily kill a minion without using mana.

Comment: He can no longer purchase Runaan's as of 5.22.

Comment: @nukeforum he can in 6.1, no doubts, tested it 5 minutes ago.

Comment: http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/bug-report/sWJgRiQ8-cant-buy-runaan-hurricane-on-thresh relevant

Comment: @Mephy Welp, I'm glad they're at least consistent with making his behavior inconsistent :)

Comment: @nukeforum I don't think it is inconsistent, it should behave exactly like Vel'Koz does. The graphical animation (the fact the weapon stays connected to him) is very misleading though.

Comment: There's no way to salvage the question/answer at this point. But I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Mephy Actually, it has been historically inconsistent since his auto has separate animations for close range and long range from the very beginning. On top of that, in patch 5.22 (at the very least, if not several more patches) he lost the ability to purchase Runaan's Hurricane because of its restriction to ranged champions.

Comment: Added the patch notes linking to the bug fix documentation (answer text has been corrected).

Comment: Ah, neat. Thanks. Definitely accepting your answer now. Probably should revise mine so that the most voted one isn't misinformation.

Answer (score 8):

This confusion comes from misinformation that Thresh is no longer able to build Runaan's Hurricane. This bug was fixed in patch 5.23.

The Relic Shield appears to execute properly at times solely because of the bonus damage from Flay.

The important thing to remember is that the Relic Shield effect still works even if you don't proc the execute. As long as you get the last hit, it will proc its heal/gold share. The last hit for the heal/gold proc can be performed with any source of damage whether from auto attack or skill.

Comment: And trying to get a last hit with somebody like Janna is quite... hard...

Comment: @Bl00dylicious Just shield yourself ;)

Comment: @nukeforum true, but thats a mana burn for little reward

Comment: @nickson104 I was being sarcastic :)

Comment: isn't the title a bit misleading? I mean, it never executes with thresh, to me the title sounds like it sometimes does sometimes not :)

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer I just emulated what the actual question sounds like from people who don't know. It sounds misleading because those people are generally misled. As I explained in my answer, people generally tend to mix up the Flay bonus damage with landing the Relic execute.

Comment: sounds legit to me! take my upvotes !

Comment: Might want to make a note that using an ability to kill minions will also make relic shield proc, just not execute unless it's coded as a melee attack, i.e. GP q

Comment: @Dragonrage I thought it would be obvious from the previous verbiage, but I think you're correct, it does need clarification.

Comment: Is that new? I know you used to be able to get hurricane on him a bit back

Comment: @Aequitas Yes, it is relatively new. Somewhere mid/late last year. There's no note of it in any patch notes, but you'll see a lot of bug reports involving his inability to use Runaan's starting at around September/October of last year. And, of course, you can see that you can't build Runaan's in game.

Comment: @nukeforum Yes thats what always confused me. I though i was lagging/it was buggy. Thanks for explanation.